How does std::basic_const_iterator support `it1 - it2`
Maybe it's a silly question, but I'm stuck on it now.
How does the following code work?
// g++ main.cpp -std=c++23

#include <iterator>

int main() {
    using It = std::basic_const_iterator<int*>;
    using CIt = std::basic_const_iterator<const int*>;

    It it1, it2;
    CIt cit;
    auto d1 = it1 - it2;  // ?
    auto d2 = it1 - cit;  // ?
}

From cppreference and GCC source, there is no operator - for two basic_const_iterators. The defined operator -s are:

basic_const_iterator::operator-( const Sentinel& s ) (cppref, source)
friend operator-( const Sentinel& s, const basic_const_iterator& i ) (cppref, source)
friend operator-( const basic_const_iterator& i, difference_type n ) (cppref, source)

Could someone explain how it1 - it2 and it1 - cit would work? Thanks!

Doesn't a basic_const_iterator satisfy basic_const_iterator::operator-( const Sentinel& s )?

What is that? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/basic_const_iterator/operator- It just calls auto d1 = it1.operator-(it2);.

As many others have commented (thanks!), it1 - it2 calls it1.operator -(it2), or precisely:
template< std::sized_sentinel_for<Iter> S >
constexpr difference_type operator-( const S& s ) const;

cppreference
But still I wasn't satisfied because they didn't explain why. So I did a bit research myself.
Here is how it works:
(using It = basic_const_iterator<int *>)

it1 - it2 ==> it1.operator -(it2), because

sized_sentinel_for<It, int*> (ref) is true, because

It == int* ==> It::operator ==(int*) (ref), because

size_sentinel_for<int*, int*> is true.


int* == It is valid (why?)
It - int* ==> It::operator -(int*), because

sized_sentinel_for<int*, int*> is true.


int* - It ==> operator -(int*, It) (ref), because

sized_sentinel_for<int*, int*> is true.







The missing part of the puzzle was int* == It, until I tried the following code:
struct A {
    constexpr bool operator ==(int) const { return true; }
};

int main() {
    static_assert(1 == A{});
}

int == A can be synthesized from A::operator ==(int) in the new C++!
(Seems the feature was introduced in C++20. Could someone point me to the Standard?)
So finally:

int* == It ==> It::operator ==(int*), because

Synthesized
size_sentinel_for<int*, int*> is true.



Update
Actually, operator <=> has the same synthesising, but not 2nd comparisons (!=, <, >, <=, >=):
#include <compare>

struct A {
    constexpr bool operator ==(int) const { return true; }
    constexpr auto operator <=>(int) const { return std::strong_ordering::equal; }
};

int main() {
    static_assert(1 == A{});
    static_assert((1 <=> A{}) == std::strong_ordering::equal);
}


In it1 - it2, S is basic_const_iterator<int*>, not int*. it1 - it2 calls it1.current_ - it2 which calls it1.current_ - it2.current_.

@Barry S is It which is basic_const_iterator<int*> in my above answer.


Could someone explain how it1 - it2 would work?

This is equivalent to writing it1.operator-(it2) which uses the overloaded operator- verison 1.
Note that this selected overload is a member function as can be seen from the omitted friend specifier in the declaration of operator- in the standard c++.

template< std::sized_sentinel_for<Iter> S >
constexpr difference_type operator-( const S& s ) const; (1)  (since C++23)


When we apply this to it1.operator-(it2), one possible instantiation will be:
long std::basic_const_iterator<int*>::operator-<std::basic_const_iterator<int*> >(std::basic_const_iterator<int*> const&) const;

Here Iter = std::basic_const_iterator<int*> ,
and difference_type = long

Thanks! Could you explain why it's chosen? More specifically, how does It satisfy sized_sentinel_for<Iter>?

@DoZerg Note that the Iter in std::sized_sentinel_for<Iter> S is the class template parameter Iter.
